# Varias teclas al mismo tiempo en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy creando un juego de una batería musical en pygame, prácticamente ya esta casi todo hecho solo me falta añadirle animaciones.

Mi problema radica en que al tocar varios tambores a la vez, es decir, varias teclas a la vez, pues resulta que solo suena un o dos tambores y otros dejan de sonar.

La verdad no se porque sucede esto,no creo que sea por mi teclado pero espero me puedan ayudar a solucionarlo.
Gracias de antemano 
Ahi les va mi codigo feo:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 513)
pygame.init()
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,576))
pygame.display.set_caption("DrumTico")
fondo = pygame.image.load("Sources/Fondoperro.jpg")
pantalla.blit(fondo,(0,0))
while True:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()   
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == K_c or evento.key == K_v :
                tarola = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/tarola.wav")
                tarola.play()
            elif evento.key == K_b:
                bombo = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Bombo.wav")
                bombo.play()
            elif evento.key == K_d or evento.key == K_f :
                tom1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Tom1.wav")
                tom1.play()
            elif evento.key == K_g or evento.key == K_h :
                tom2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Tom2.wav")
                tom2.play()
            elif evento.key == K_j or evento.key == K_k :
                tom3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Tom3.wav")
                tom3.play()
            elif evento.key == K_x:
                hhCerrado = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/HH Cerrado.wav")
                hhCerrado.play()
            elif evento.key == K_z:
                hhAbierto = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/HH Abierto.wav")
                hhAbierto.play()
            elif evento.key == K_r:
                crash = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Crash.wav")
                crash.play()
            elif evento.key == K_u:
                ride = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Ride.wav")
                ride.play()
            elif evento.key == K_y:
                crashRide = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/CrashRide.wav")
                crashRide.play()
            elif evento.key == K_i:
                campana = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sources/Campana.wav")
                campana.play()               
    pygame.display.update()
```

Les dejó un link de un vídeo de prueba, a partir del segundo 40 se ve que las teclas se enredan entre si.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kx9sDRWW10U&feature=youtu.be

Gracias